# Heroku deployment throws an error every time: Missing script: "build"

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, mern

everyone. I've been trying to deploy a simple MERN application on Heroku for some time now, unfortunately without success so far! I usually get the error message from Heroku (See below).
I did everything exactly according to the plan as described here https://github.com/safak/youtube/tree/free-deployment for a FullStack App. I also have other applications that have also been successfully deployed on Heroku, with the same structure. However, there was no problem. Have I overlooked something?

> remote: npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
> remote: npm ERR!
> remote: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
> remote: npm ERR! npm run.

```
 {
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
 "start": "node index.js",
 "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
},
"engines": {
 "node": "18.6.0"
},
 "cacheDirectories": [
 "node_modules",
 "client/node_modules"
],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.1",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"mongoose": "^6.5.2",
"nodemon": "^2.0.19",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
 }
}
```

Comment: Watching your `package.json`, inside the `heroku-postbuild` script you specified `npm run build`. This force the server to search inside your `scripts` object a the `build` script which is not defined, so it throws the error

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. How would I have to change this line so that I can deploy successfully?

Comment: Try by adding `"build": "react-scripts build"` into the `scripts` object.